# How can i show a arraylist content in a datagridview c#?

Tags: c#

this is a struct that contains informations of the trainee

```
public struct Stagaire
{
  public string nom;
  public string pre_nom;
  public string date;
  public string fillier;
  public int num;
}
```

this Arraylist is to stock every new trainee

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
```

this is the code of adding a Stagaire to Arraylist

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stagaire stg = new Stagaire();
  stg.nom = textBox1.Text;
  stg.pre_nom = prenom.Text;
  stg.date = date.Text;
  stg.fillier = fill.Text;
  stg.num = Convert.ToInt32(num.Text);
  ar.Add(stg);
}
```

how i can show any Stagaire informations in a datagridview ?

Comment: Use properties instead of fields. Just add `{ get; set; }` to all. Then use data binding: `dataGridView.DataSource = ar;`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using ArrayList vs List<Stagaire> ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of `struct`.
Use `properties` instead of `fields`.
Use the accepted naming conventions.

```
public class Stagaire
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string PreNom { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Fillier { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

Use strongly-typed collection instead of `ArrayList`.
Use `BindingList` to automatically track the item in the collection.
Give it a suitable name.

```
BindingList<Stagaire> stagaires = new BindingList<Stagaire>();
```

Use data binding instead of manually populating.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = stagaires;
```

Thanks to the data binding DataGridView will be updated automatically.

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stagaire = new Stagaire();
    // Here the code of filling properties

    stagaires.Add(stagaire);
}
```

Also I would have changed the `Date` property type to `DateTime`.

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

And would use a `DateTimePicker` for the date input.

```
stagaire.Date = dateTimePicker.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

for datagridview you have to add a new stagaire and to affect the ar[i] to the nes stagaire then you have to add avery inforation of the new stagaire to the datagridview

```
Stagaire sgt = new Stagaire();
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Count; i++)

        {
            sgt = (Stagaire)ar[i];//ar[i] is an Object so you have to convert it (caste) to the Stagaire type 
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sgt.nom,sgt.pre_nom,sgt.date,sgt.num,sgt.fillier);

        }
```